# Zend Framework 2 REST api

Tags: php, rest, oop, asp.net-web-api, zend-framework2

I have a small problem. I am new in Zend Framework 2 and I wanted to create a REST service with it.

I followed his tutorial: http://www.slideshare.net/mikestowe/building-a-rest-api-with-zend-framework-2

The problem is that I get an error message and I didn't find it anywhere on google.

**Fatal error: Declaration of Application\Controller\UserController::setEventManager() must be compatible with Zend\EventManager\EventManagerAwareInterface::setEventManager(Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface $eventManager) in C:\wamp\www\zf2rest\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\UserController.php on line 15**

This is my UserController:

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;

class UserController extends AbstractRestfulController {
protected $collectionOptions = array('GET', 'POST');
protected $resourceOptions = array('GET', 'POST', 'DELETE');

protected function _getOptions() {
    if($this->params->fromRoute('id', false)) {
        // we have an id, return specific item
        return $this->resourceOptions;
    }
    //no ID, return collection
    return $this->collectionOptions;
}

public function options() {
    $response = $this->getResponse();

    //If in Options Array, Allow
    $response->getHeaders()
            ->addHeaderLine('Allow', implode(',', $this->_getOptions()));

    //return Response
    return $response;
}

public function setEventManager(EventManagerInterface $events) {
    //events propery defined in AbstractController
    $this->events = $events;

    //Register the listener and callback method with a priority if 10
    $events->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'checkOptions'), 10);
}

public function checkOptions($e) {
    if(in_array($e->getRequest()->getMethod(), $this->_getOptions())) {
        //Method Allowed, Nothing to do
        return;
    }

    //Method Not Allowed
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response->setStatusCode(405);
    return $response;
}
}
```

Does anyone know a solution for this ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interface enforces setEventManager::$events is a class implementing the interface Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface; you have however broken this as EventManagerInterface is just a alias to the fully qualified class name.

You can avoid this by either, using the fully qualified class name

```
public function setEventManager(\Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface $events);
```

Alternatively, keep what you have and just add a namespace alias at the top of the class.

```
<?php
    namespace Api/Controller;

    use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInteface;
```

What is also really important is to ensure you call the parent setEventManager() otherwise all of the default configuration is overloaded, just take a look at what else is set.

```
public function setEventManager(EventManagerInterface $events)
{
    parent::setEventManager($events);

    $events->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'checkOptions'), 10);
}
```